# Authentication and Authorization in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, authorization, basic-authentication

I am using jboss server. I want to do BASIC authentication using web.xml file. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried googling first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial on [How to Configure JBoss for Basic Authentication](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/880/) should help you in this

Comment: I went through the link. A bit of explanation will help.

Answer (score 2):

The steps are

1. Add security-constraint in web.xml for secure pages
2. Apply login-config in web.xml
3. In jboss-web.xml apply security-domain
4. Create properties files for user and roles

The following link explains this pretty well with an example
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/BASICAuthentication

users.properties file uses a format:

```
username1=password1
username2=password2
```

roles.properties file uses a format:

```
username1=role1,role2,...
username1.RoleGroup1=role3,role4,...
username2=role1,role3,...
```

This link gives more details about the user and role properties file.
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsersRolesLoginModule

Comment: I did not get what values should be entered in user.properties and role.properties file.